# Including two bundles which are using the same subbundle

Tags: symfony, twitter-bootstrap, composer-php, sonata-admin

Im trying to use the following two bundles in my symfony2.1 project:

- [sonata-admin bundle](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle)
- [braincrafted bootstrap-bundle](https://github.com/braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle)

My problem is, the two bundles use both [knp-menu bundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenu).
But sonata needs 1.1.x-dev of knp-menu bundle
and braincrafted bootstrap-bundle dev-master.

With the following composer settings i get the following error.
Composer.json:

> ```
>     "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "dev-master",
>     "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "dev-master",
>     "sonata-project/intl-bundle": "dev-master",
>     "sonata-project/cache-bundle": "dev-master",
>     "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "1.1.x-dev",
>     "braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle": "dev-develop"
> ```

Error:
Knp\Menu\Matcher\Voter\VoterInterface' not found in vendor/braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle/Braincrafted/BootstrapBundle/Voter/RequestVoter

I know that the Matcher doesn't exist in the early knp menu bundle version. But if i change the knp menu bundle version to:

> "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "dev-master",

it isn't possible to install the sonata admin bundle. The following error occurs if i execute the command "composer.phar update"

```
  Problem 1
    - sonata-project/admin-bundle dev-master requires knplabs/knp-menu-bundle >=1.1.0,<2.0.x-dev -> satisfiable by knplabs/knp-menu-bundle 1.1.x-dev, knplabs/knp-menu-bundle 1.1.x-dev, knplabs/knp-menu-bundle v1.1.0.
    - sonata-project/admin-bundle dev-master requires knplabs/knp-menu-bundle >=1.1.0,<2.0.x-dev -> satisfiable by knplabs/knp-menu-bundle 1.1.x-dev, knplabs/knp-menu-bundle 1.1.x-dev, knplabs/knp-menu-bundle v1.1.0.
    - Can only install one of: knplabs/knp-menu-bundle dev-master, knplabs/knp-menu-bundle 1.1.x-dev.
    - Can only install one of: knplabs/knp-menu-bundle dev-master, knplabs/knp-menu-bundle 1.1.x-dev.
    - Can only install one of: knplabs/knp-menu-bundle v1.1.0, knplabs/knp-menu-bundle dev-master.
    - Installation request for knplabs/knp-menu-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by knplabs/knp-menu-bundle dev-master.
    - Installation request for sonata-project/admin-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by sonata-project/admin-bundle dev-master.
```

Has someone an idea how can i use both bundles or isn't there a way? Thanks for help.

Comment: Did you open a ticket for this?

Comment: no, but a ticket with this problem is already open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a temporary solution to use both bundles until this [ticket](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/1234) is resolved.

I defined a repository in my composer.json file and manipulated the sonata admin bundle requirements **("knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "dev-master"):**

```
"repositories": [
{
    "type": "package",             
    "package": {
        "name": "sonata-project/admin-bundle",
        "type": "symfony-bundle",
        "description": "Symfony SonataAdminBundle",
        "keywords": ["Admin Generator", "admin", "sonata", "bootstrap"],
        "homepage": "http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin",
        "license": "MIT",
        "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Thomas Rabaix",
            "email": "thomas.rabaix@sonata-project.org",
            "homepage": "http://sonata-project.org"
        },
        {
            "name": "Sonata Community",
            "homepage": "https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/contributors"
        }
        ],
        "require": {
            "symfony/http-foundation": ">=2.1,<2.3-dev",
            "symfony/form": ">=2.1,<2.3-dev",
            "symfony/validator": ">=2.1,<2.3-dev",
            "symfony/security-bundle": ">=2.1,<2.3-dev",
            "symfony/routing": ">=2.1,<2.3-dev",
            "symfony/config": ">=2.1,<2.3-dev",
            "symfony/console": ">=2.1,<2.3-dev",
            "symfony/twig-bridge": ">=2.1,<2.3-dev",
            "twig/twig": ">=1.10,<2.0-dev",
            "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "dev-master",
            "sonata-project/jquery-bundle": "dev-master",
            "sonata-project/exporter": "dev-master",
            "sonata-project/block-bundle": "dev-master",
            "doctrine/common": ">=2.2,<3.0"
        },
        "require-dev": {
            "jms/translation-bundle": "*"
        },
        "suggest": {
            "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "dev-master",
            "sonata-project/intl-bundle": "dev-master"
        },
        "autoload": {
            "psr-0": {
                "Sonata\\AdminBundle": ""
            }
        },
        "target-dir": "Sonata/AdminBundle",            
        "version": "dev-master",
        "source": {
            "url": "git://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle.git",
            "type": "git",
            "reference": "0269691d61764798537a2fd3b13bfafbfb387eef"
        }                   

    }
}
```

Then i had to overwrite the method buildSideMenu in the admin class, because the method setCurrentUri() doesn't exist anymore (is now named setUri()). And all my own admin classes extend now MyAdmin

```
abstract class MyAdmin extends Admin
{

    /**
     * Build the side menu related to the current action
     *
     * @param string                                   $action
     * @param \Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AdminInterface $childAdmin
     *
     * @return \Knp\Menu\ItemInterface|boolean
     */
    public function buildSideMenu($action, AdminInterface $childAdmin = null)
    {
        if ($this->loaded['side_menu']) {
            return;
        }

        $this->loaded['side_menu'] = true;

        $menu = $this->menuFactory->createItem('root');
        $menu->setChildrenAttribute('class', 'nav nav-list');
        $menu->setUri($this->getRequest()->getBaseUrl().$this->getRequest()->getPathInfo());

        $this->configureSideMenu($menu, $action, $childAdmin);

        foreach ($this->getExtensions() as $extension) {
            $extension->configureSideMenu($this, $menu, $action, $childAdmin);
        }

        $this->menu = $menu;
    }


}
```

I know this isn't the best solution but it worked for my purpose

Answer (score 1):

Edit composer.json and modify the line with reference to knp-menu-bundle to look like this:
**"knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "1.1.x-dev",**

It needs a version >=1.1.0,<2.0.x-dev which is stated in the first line of the error.

That works for me.

Comment: but then the braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle isn't working anymore, cause it needs "dev-master" and the knp menu bundle dev-master ist over 2.0.x

Answer (score 0):

Using the Composer you cannot use both bundles. Actually you should open a ticket in the https://github.com/braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle and explain the situation. They should update the composer.json of the project to allow people to use the current version of KnpMenu and not only the most recent version.